# GruntJS - How to add a line to grunt.js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am a total newbie to this so I can't figure this one out. I have successfully installed GruntJS via npm, but now have to add something to my grunt.js file. How do I do it? Does this file need to be placed in my projects JavaScript folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gruntfile should be placed at the root of your project.

I would start by reading the [docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki).